# Finding words in a file does not work correctly

Tags: c, string, file

I am making a function in C that reads file and finds the word that are not in a comment and in string(e.g. printf("Hello world") I need only printf, "hello" and "world" must not be counted) but in some files my program counts also the words in string

```
int isDelimiter(char *delim, char c){
  int i = 0;
  while (delim[i])
  {
    if (delim[i] == c)
        return 1;
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}

int getIdentifiers(FILE *filePointer){

  char line[256], identifier[100];

  //char delimiters[] = "\n\[]();~`!=><|*/:&% \t\"{},-+#^$'&";
  char delimiters[] = {'\n', '\"', '[', ']', '(', ')', ';', '~', '`', 
    '!', '=', '<','>', '|', '*','/',':','&',
    '%','\t', '{', '}', ',','-','+','#','^','$','&','\0'};

  int cnt=0, inWord=0, isString=0, isSingleLineComment=0, 
     isMultiComment=0, isChar=0;

  rewind(filePointer);

  while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), filePointer)!=NULL){

    int i=0, j=0;

    isSingleLineComment=0;

    while(line[i]){

      //multi line comment check
      if(line[i]=='/' && line[i+1]=='*') isMultiComment=1;

      //single line comment
      if(line[i]=='/' && line[i+1]=='/') isSingleLineComment=1;

      //ending multi line comment
      if(line[i]=='*' && line[i+1]=='/' && isMultiComment==1) isMultiComment=0;

      //checking for string
      if(line[i]=='"' && isString==0) isString=1;

      //check if assignment char is in quote
      if(line[i]=='\'' && isChar==0) isChar =1;
      else if(line[i]=='\'' && isChar==1) isChar=0;

      //splitting textline into words
      if(inWord==0){
        if(!isDelimiter(delimiters, line[i])) {
          inWord = 1;
          identifier[j] = line[i];
          j++;
        } else {
          i++;
          continue;
        }
      } else {
        //ending word
        if(isDelimiter(delimiters, line[i])) {
          if(line[i]=='"' ) isString=1;

          inWord=0;
          identifier[j]= '\0';
          j=0;

          // identifier checking
          if(!isString && !isMultiComment && !isSingleLineComment && 
             !isChar &&
             !isdigit(identifier[0])){
             cnt++;
          }
        } else {
          identifier[j]= line[i];
          j++;
        }
      }

      if(line[i]=='"' && isString){
        isString=0;
      }
      i++;
    }
  }

  return cnt;
}
```

The file that i test contains:

> int a;
>            
>  //int c;
>            
>  /*int k;
>            
>  */
>            
>  "int i;\"int c;"
>            
>  int =e;

The expected return value must be 4(the words i need are 'int', 'a', 'int' and 'e' but the value is 2.

Comment: Simple question - but any reason why you chose C to do this?  Higher level languages make it muck easier to do string manipulations and usually have better built-in libraries.

Comment: I have a university project and it must be in C otherwise I would use Java for this task

Comment: What you are asking is not trivial.  Getting comment blocks correct and dealing with weird edge cases like : `// /*` make this a real debugging task.  I cleaned up your paste above, but now, I will ask you how much time an effort you have put in with your debugger?  Walking through it should tell you when things are not working as expected.  Also, your "int..." line - are you missing a double quote here?  Otherwise, I would see 6 values with your requirements.

Comment: You may want to roll in a C regular expression library and side-step all this messy parsing. You'll end up writing your own by accident if you're not careful.

Comment: `strtok()` will help with delimiting if you wish as well.

Comment: FYI on the quote step - I missed that you had "quoted" the quote with a backslash C-Style.  Gonna have to add code to check for that too.

Comment: More advice - You have tried to do everything at once and caused somewhat of a train wreck.  Instead, first, get a word counter working, then get it working with delimiters, then add `//` checks, then add more... until you have a working prototype.  This will help you keep it all working together correctly.  When you do it all at once, you have no idea where any bugs actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @MichaelDorgan's comment, there are several other edge cases you need to deal with regarding strings.  Both of these will cause your current parser to fail:

```
"This string \" contains a double quote"
"This one contains ' a single quote"
```

I would strongly advise changing the fundamental architecture of the parser to start in a state where words are recognized, but if you see any of `/*` `//` `"` or `'` you switch to a state that (A) ignores words, and (B) uses a separate loop to consume input until it correctly recognizes a valid termination for the current state, after which it returns to the initial state.

So `/*` will continue to read text until it finds a `*/`, while `//` simply discards the remainder of the current line and then resets.  Likewise `"` and `'` scan forward till they find a second unescaped copy, ignoring everything else.  You'll need to pay special attention to backslashes in this mode so you correctly process things like `"\""`, `"\\"` `"\\\""` etc.

Comment: Notice also that all OP's current special comment cases are only checking from the first character of the string...